# implement erase function to my class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, c++11, stl

I'm trying to implement erase function  to my square list function but when I write mine it give me this compiler error

> Error 1   error C2664: 'square_list::erase' : cannot convert
>   parameter 1 from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>' to 'int *'

main code

```
#define nullptr NULL
template <typename T_>
class square_list
{



    void erase(iterator it)
    {
        data.erase(it);
    }


};
```

Comment: can show us the definition of sqLoc

Comment: @michaeltang I don't know is iterator and pass iterator to my function ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the erase function to take the std::list iterator, as follows:

```
void erase(typename std::list<value_type>::iterator it)
{
    data.erase(it);
}
```

Live example: http://ideone.com/c3T9Hs

Answer (score 1):

`std::list<T>::erase` takes a list::iterator as argument, but you are trying to pass it a `square_list<T>::iterator`, a.k.a. a `T*`.

I would question the logic of defining iterators as `T*` for a `squared_list<T>`, while simultaneously exposing `list<T>::iterator`s to the underlying list in the public interface (`begin()` and `end()1), as this breaks encapsulation.

Nevertheless, if you want to proceed, you can do something like this:

```
void erase(typename std::list<T>::iterator it)
{
    data.erase(it);
}
```

Or, if you want to actually use the iterators that you define in your `squared_list` class:

```
void erase(iterator it)
{
    // look for the underlying list iterator pointing to this value
    auto underlyingIt = std::find_if(data.begin(), data.end(), [=](const T& node) {
       return (&node == it);  
    });
    if (underlyingIt != data.end()) {
         data.erase(underlyingIt);
    } else {
         // handle case where the "iterator" is not found here 
    }
}
```

Comment: When he is calling sqi.begin() he is getting the std::list<int>::iterator. But his erase function is expecting an int*.  So I think if his erase function was modified to take std::list<value_type>::iterator, it might work

Comment: @sajas I try that but because of auto sqLoc = sqi.begin(); it convert ti to int ??

Comment: The int* error conversion you get comes from the implementation of your `erase()` method, not from its calling site